# How to aggregate counts of pandas column based on 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as shown in the image below. I currently have 2 columns showing the injury someone suffered and the column next to it represents the game missed by that person (1 if they missed the game due to injury and No Injury if they didn't miss the game due to the injury). In the third column instead of the Nan I would like to have an aggregation of the number of games the player missed due to an injury. So as you can see the player had a concussion and missed a game in the first week but not in the next. So due to the concussion he missed 1 game. I would like the row to then look like:

```
Injury       Game Missed    Games Missed Due To Injury
Concussion       1                (Concussion,1)
Concussion       0                (Concussion,1)
No Injury        No Injury        Nan
Shoulder         1                (Shoulder,1)
Shoulder         No Injury        (Shoulder,1)
Shoulder         1                (Shoulder,2)
Shoulder         1                (Shoulder,3)
```

How could I achieve this in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to calculate the [`cumsum`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), before this use [`pd.to_numeric`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) 
to replace 'No Injury' with '0' in order to convert to an integer( [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)) to calculate the cumulative sum.
Once the sum is calculated, convert to str and join it to the Injury column using [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) :

```
 missed=pd.to_numeric(df['Game Missed'],errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int).groupby(df['Injury']).cumsum()  
df['Games Missed Due To Injury']=( missed.astype(str)
                                         .str.cat(df['Injury'],sep=',')
                                         .mask(df['Injury'].str.contains('No')) )
print(df)
```

---

```
       Injury Game Missed Games Missed Due To Injury
0  Concussion           1               1,Concussion
1  Concussion           0               1,Concussion
2   No Injury   No Injury                        NaN
3    Shoulder           1                 1,Shoulder
4    Shoulder   No Injury                 1,Shoulder
5    Shoulder           1                 2,Shoulder
6    Shoulder           1                 3,Shoulder
```

Note, you can use the mask that you need:

```
df['Injury'].str.contains('No')
df['Injury'].eq('No Injury')
df['Injury'].str.contains('No Injury',case=False)
```

Comment: Is there a book where I can read these pandas shortcuts? I can do everything using for loops and df.iterrows but the only reason i post so much is because thats slow and inefficient and I want to learn the short ways of doing these things.

Comment: Surely there are books but I think you can learn a lot by consulting the libraries and above all by visiting other questions and answers in this forum. It is tremendously instructive.

Comment: You are right that you can do everything with loops but you really have to know how to use all methods efficiently. Consider accepting or voting if my answer satisfies your question :)

Comment: When I try to use the missed code you provided I get TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'.

Comment: In the No Injury column are there upper and lower case letters in the cells that contain No Injury? I mean no injury, no injury, NO injury?

Comment: try: `df['Injury'].str.contains('No Injury',case=False )` or `df['Injury'].str.contains('No',case=False )` in the first line

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-e82f0f6e4c5d> in <module>
----> 1 missed= (injury_and_measureables_dropped['injured_this_week'].mask(injury_and_measureables_dropped['injured_this_week'].str.contains('No'),'0')

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

I've also posted an extra picture of the data I am working with in the post. Perhaps itll make the data im working with clearer.

Comment: try: `na=False`,`df['Injury'].str.contains('No Injury',case=False ,na=False)`or `df['Injury'].str.contains('No' ,na=False)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202020/discussion-between-soccer-analytics-fan-and-ansev).